# Use docker in restricted internet environnement

Tags: docker

I'm planning to use docker in a restricted internet access environment controlled by squid proxy...
And i can't find a way to retrieve urls used by docker under the hood when pulling image.
Could you please help me finding these url in order to add rules for docker repositories

Comment: I added the following two URLs
registry.hub.docker.com
index.docker.io
But the result is the same (images not downloaded). So I used a tcpdump to retrieve domain names to trust and the content was too wordy so it was too difficult to find which urls to include in proxy ..

Answer (score 0):

Guess it's quite difficult to find out the exact URLs that are used when Docker is performing the image pull. But at least there is workaround that can give you the list of external servers the Docker interacts with:

```
# Console #1    
sudo tcpdump | grep http | awk '{ gsub(":",""); print $3 "\n" $5 }' | grep -v $YOUR_OWN_FQDN > servers 2&>1

# Console #2
docker pull debian

# Console #1
sed -e 's/\.http\(s\)\?//g' servers | sort -u
```

I've end up with this list (unfortunately I'm note sure if it's consistent or region-independent):

```
104.16.105.85
ec2-54-152-161-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-54-208-130-47.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-54-208-162-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com
server-205-251-219-168.arn1.r.cloudfront.net
server-205-251-219-226.arn1.r.cloudfront.net
```